# How to Make a new post listed down on wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I am newbie in Wordpress. My blog have 28 post total. Is there any option to create a new post and make it's position 5th or 20th or last?

Comment: go to Dashboard => Posts => Add a new Post

Comment: It is not creating a new post (I mentioned that i already have 28 post.) I want to rearrange my post.

Comment: you said  in question :- "Is there any option to create a new post"

Comment: Sentence didn't stop  there.

Comment: Ok thank for your answer. But it is not what I am looking for. Look, I didn't edit post. 
A joke "You are a dog Lover persion"
If you only read "You are a dog" you read wrong. Okay?

Answer (score 0):

You can use plugin for that, such as [My Post Order](https://wordpress.org/plugins/my-posts-order/) or you can change the `Published Time` by editing the post.

Comment: I'will try "my post order"
No, Published time will be actual time(if possible)...
If wordpress short posts based on only date then I may have no choice but changing date. If there any "ID of post" or something like that exists on wp then I may can change order without changing date.

Comment: That is why My Post Order will be the proper solution, since it will allow for you to sort them without modifying the published time.